# Hibernate Criteria for tables with more than one relationsship

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I've got a database with two tables (City, Country) and two relations between them.

The first one is the "a country has multiple cities" relation.

```
select * from City inner join Country on(code=countrycode);
```

The second one is the "a country has one capital" relation.

```
select * from City inner join Country on(capital=id);
```

Hibernate criterias work fine for the first relation, e.g.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(City.class);
List<City> = criteria
                .createCriteria("countrycode")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("continent", continent))
                .list();
```

But how can I create an Hibernate criteria to retrieve a list of capitals? The second relation is unmapped. Does Hibernate support this kind of relationship?

The City class:

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "countrycode", nullable = false)
    private Country countrycode;

    ...
```

The Country class:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = City.class, mappedBy = "countrycode")
    private Set<City> cities;

    private Integer capital;

    ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't capital be in the City entity to state whether or not a specific City is the capital?

Comment: I'm using the sample database `world` from mysql.com. An extra boolean field in the city table is unnecessary IMHO. I can retrieve a list of capitals already via  Hibernate query language's theta join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information whether or not the city is capital of any country has to be within City. Add a boolean field to City an query it like that:

```
List<City> = session.createCriteria(City.class)
                .createCriteria("countrycode")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("continent", continent))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("capital", true))
                .list();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Journeycorner. Meanwhile I found the information that's not possible to use Hibernate's criteria api in conjunction with unmapped relations. However, I'm accepting your answer.